# Sending request to webserver using axios

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I want to send an array of strings over localhost 3000 with route  `start` then send back a response with status 200 and eventually a map attached to response.body Currently i have this
Client code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
let listOfNames = ['mikey'];
axios.post(''http://localhost:3000/start'', {
        data: { names: listOfNames }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const port = 3000
var listOfNames = [];
app.post('/start', async (req, res) => {
  listOfNames = req.params.listOfNames;
  res.status(200).send("Names added");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('request recieved');
});
```

I get this error presemably from how the request is being sent, any help?

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:645:5)
    at dispatchHttpRequest (C:\Users\cmb\rectangleHealth\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:23
94:20)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at http (C:\Users\cmb\rectangleHealth\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:2330:10)
    at Axios.dispatchRequest (C:\Users\cmb\rectangleHealth\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:
3260:10)
    at Axios.request (C:\Users\cmb\rectangleHealth\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:3610:33)
    at Axios.httpMethod [as post] (C:\Users\cmb\rectangleHealth\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios
.cjs:3649:19)
    at Function.wrap [as post] (C:\Users\cmb\rectangleHealth\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cj
s:27:15) {
  input: '/start',
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
}
```

Edit: New error ECONNRESET error emerging from applied fixes

```
AxiosError: read ECONNRESET
    at AxiosError.from (C:\Users\cmb\rectangleHealth\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:789:14
)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (C:\Users\cmb\rectangleHealth\node_modules\axios\dis
t\node\axios.cjs:2744:25)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at eventHandlers.<computed> (C:\Users\cmb\rectangleHealth\node_modules\follow-redirects\index.
js:14:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  errno: -4077,
```

The console also outputs a 2 json objects called request and config that cannot fit into this post.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed 2 things errors in your code:

First, check your url is correct, instead of

''http://localhost:3000/start'' (you have multiple single quotes wrapping the url)

try,

"http://localhost:3000/start" or 'http://localhost:3000/start' (wrap it in proper double quotes or single quotes)

Second, You are passing the data in your api call as request body and not as request parameters, but you are trying to access it in the parameters of your api.

You should try accessing the request's body on the server side instead of parameters,

```
app.post('/start', async (req, res) => {
  listOfNames = req.body.listOfNames;
  res.status(200).send("Names added");
});
```

Else you might probably face issue while accessing the data in api as well.

Comment: this was helpful but axios is now throwing a ECONNRESET error, a quick search told me this comes from the connection abruptly dropping on either end. At first I thought I was referencing to my listOfNames incorrectly, but after changing it to req.body.names as in the request, the error persists. Any tips?

Comment: @macman926 Can you share the error logs for reference?

Comment: accidentally added to you comment, my b